# Does JasperReports allow dynamic font color?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have in DB a textfield with HEX color property, for example:

```
**Name, Color**
John Doe, #FF0000
Albert Smith, #AF0FBA
```

How can i pass these HEX values through jrxml to render font color properly?
Conditional styling didn't match, because i have over 16 millions of colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following property to the text element:

```
<textField>
  <reportElement ...>
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor">$F{color}</propertyExpression>
  </reportElement>
  ...
```